# Why is the time complexity for insertion of a string into an unordered_map, constant on average?

Tags: c++, hash, stl

If we have a string of length n, then shouldn't the time for inserting it into an unordered_map (C++) be O(n)? But in the  [cplusplus.com website:](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/)

The following is written:
[image]

So, what is the correct time complexity? Thank you!

Comment: The length of the string will not have an impact on the time it takes to insert.

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't make sense, because you are using `n` in a different way than the base in the complexity requirement below. That said, insertion implies copying, so it is at least the complexity of the raw copying plus whatever the container needs for itself on top.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the question makes sense, but it relies on a faulty premise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, constant time refers to the number of elements in the map, not anything about those elements.

If you have a string of size `n`, and insert it into a map of size `m`, `O(n)` insertion is constant in `m`.